# OpenMP and C++: Am I correctly making objects in a loop private?

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to add OpenMP to an existing C++ code.  I am new to OpenMP and a bit rusty with C++.  I have a loop that isn't working as expected, even with just a single OpenMP thread, and I am wondering if I am leaving something out.

I have a class that just stores a bunch of data:

```
class Properties {
   double thing1;
   double thing2[10];
   double thing3;
}
```

Then there's the class of central interest.  Several of its properties can be stored in the above `Properties` class:

```
  class MainThing {
       // usual constructors etc.
       double thing1;
       double thing2[10];
       double thing3;
       void ShowProps(Properties *pProp);
       // other functionality
    }
    void MainThing::ShowProps(Properties pProp) {
       // just copies the various properties of object into pProp
    }
```

Then there's the main code.  I define an array of MainThing objects, loop through the array, call ShowProps for each object in the array, and process the properties thus obtained.

```
   int main() {

       int i, num_objs;
       Properties props;
       MainThing *current_obj;
       MainThing *main_objs;
       // allocate and instantiate elements of main_objs

    #pragma omp parallel shared(main_objs, num_objs)
    {
    #pragma omp for private(i, current_obj, props)
       for (i=0; i<num_objs; i++) {
          current_obj = main_objs+i;
          current_obj->ShowProps(&props);
          // do lots of stuff with "props"
          // this loop is "embarrassingly parallel"
          // no dependence from one iteration to another
       }
    }  // end pragma omp parallel

    }
```

Things aren't panning out as expected, as I said.  So I just want to know, have I done all it takes to make the various objects etc. in the loop properly private?

BTW, there are probably many improvements to be made to this toy code.  And I will be happy to hear them all.  But keep in mind that I am working with someone else's code, and though I have left out many details I have paralleled its structure as closely as I could.  Only the OpenMP, such as it is, is my own work.

Comment: I'm no openMP programmer.. but it looks like you're passing the same properties reference to all threads. That may be a problem

Comment: No, if you depend on private clause, it must be on the pragma parallel, not on the pragma for.  It would look like better design if you would define current_obj and props inside the parallel so that private becomes unnecessary.  Likewise, for(int i=0;.. to make i local to loop is more idiomatic for C++, and, for the last 25 years, in C.

Comment: @tim18  As I said, I'm learning OpenMP.  I've seen several examples where the private clause is on the pragma for.  What is special about my case?  Also, I guess I'm confused about what is default private and shared.  So, I guess whatever is defined outside of pragma parallel is shared by default and whatever is defined inside it is private by default?  Thanks.

Comment: omp parallel for private() is OK but not omp for private....  private is an optional clause for parallel only.  But as I said you would be better off fixing your scopes so you don't need private.  Yes, what is in scope outside the parallel loops is shared by default.  default(none) is often recommended to catch mistakes.  What is in scope only inside the parallel is effectively private.  This makes more visible the fact that firstprivate and lastprivate are a bit more difficult.

Comment: Sorry but the question is very fuzzy. *isn't working as expected* is not a sufficient problem description and your example code is very incomplete. Please distill a [mcve] and describe your specific problem and the expected behavior.

Comment: @Zulan  The code is just too big to replicate the problem here.  I simply can't do it.  And I am simply asking whether I am doing the OpenMP correctly, given that I am dealing with objects in C++.  I am not asking anyone to solve my problem.  I am merely asking if there is anything obvious breaking of OpenMP rules in what I have done.  have I left out anything that OpenMP requires, for instance?  That seems a pretty clear question to me.  In fact, I received two answers in the comments to it.

Comment: It is impossible to give a comprehensive answer to the question as is. I did not ask you to replicate a full problem but a [mcve]. You can simplify / mock stuff, but you cannot just omit critical portions with a comment like *allocate and instantiate elements*.